# How to read rdoc in Emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs, rdoc

I'm now using to read RDoc `gem server` command.
But I want to read document in Emacs.

I found a emacs lisp for it called `[yari][1]`, but it doesn't worked in my environment.
I called a function `yari` and typed in the minibuffer `yari: Array`, but result was `yari: Array[not matched]`.

I don't insist to use `yari`, it is ok if I can read rdoc in Emacs.
Is there any way that is commonly used?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for `yari` not working is that you probably installed your `ruby` and its gems without their docs. If you're using RVM you should do this:

```
rvm docs generate
```

Comment: I think I've already installed RDoc correctly. I can see rdoc by using `gem server` and to be sure I've reinstalled all rdocs by `gem rdoc --all --ri`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gem install rdoc-data
rdoc-data --install
```